# Number of trials needed for a high chance of certain dice throws

Tags: probability, dice

We throw two cubical dice. How to show that we only need $300$ throws in order to have a $95\%$ chance that in at least $100$ throws, we’ll get a smaller number on the first cube? Is $250$ throws enough?

I thought about a Bernoulli trial, where $k=300$, $n=100$, and the probability of success is equal to $\frac{15}{36}$. But these are not calculations for a human.

Comment: the normal approximation to the bernoulli distribution should be good enough.  Note:  the mean is the number of throws times $\frac {15}{36}$.  Thus, for $250$ throws the mean is just over $104$ and $\sigma \approx 7.8$ so there is a very high probability of the first one winning fewer than $100$ times.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wolfram alpha, [there's a probability of $0.2755$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial+cumulative+distribution+n%3D250+p%3D0.41666666667+at+x%3D99) (approximately) that in $250$ throws the first die will show the smaller number fewer than $100$ times. That is, the probability that it shows the smaller number at least $100$ times is only $0.7245$, so $250$ throws are not enough to get a $95\%$ chance of that occuring.

[With $271$ throws](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial+cumulative+distribution+n%3D271+p%3D0.41666666667+at+x%3D99) there's only a probability of about $0.0484$ that the first die will show the smaller number fewer than $100$ times.  Thus $271$ throws are enough to have chance of at least $95\%$ that the first die will show the smaller number at least $100$ times.

On the other hand, [with $270$ throws](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial+cumulative+distribution+n%3D270+p%3D0.41666666667+at+x%3D99), the probability that the first die shows the lower number fewer than $100$ times is $0.0536$, so $270$ throws aren't enough to get a $95\%$  chance of the first die's showing the smaller number at least $100$ times.